# Android: put Interface to Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have a custom dialog in my app. My custom dialog I implemented as Activity with transperent background and with view like dialog. Mu custom dialog looks like alert dialog, with title, message and button. What I'm tryin to do, is to create nice interface for setting title, message and onClickListener of my popup.

Firstly I thout to put all staff to intent like:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent (this, CustomPopup.class);
 intent.putExta ("Title", "PopupTitle");
 intent.putExta ("Message", "PopupMessage");
 intent.putExtra ("OnCLickListener", ?????); //here is problem

 startActivity(intent);
```

But the problem is that is no way to pur OnCLickListener to intent.

Secondly, I tried to create class that implement Parcable.
But the problem is the same

```
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(message);
        dest.writeValue(buttonClickListener); // here is problem. I cannot write Interface
    }
```

I cannot write OnCLickListener to Parcel object.

How to be ? How  to write nice interface to my custom popup ? Because popup can have different titles and messages, and popup will be used from many activities....Thanks in advance

Comment: So, why are you not using an actual Dialog?

Comment: There is more views than just title and message, but I dont want to make my question more complicated....

Comment: Why not add a key "clicklistener" value `true` as an extra? If it's set to true, make that `OnClickListener()` in the receiving `Activity` class

Comment: becouse there can be different actions on button click. Ones it can just close popup, ones it can start another activity

Comment: why aren't you just using a dialog or dialog fragment?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with a dialog in terms of layout, the docs have an example. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that implements both OnClickListener and Serializable. Send an instance through the Intent to the "dialog".

Answer (score 0):

If the popup's behavior is that different, create subclasses of CustomPopup that contains those behaviors. You can still pass in the data that those listeners need to act on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @toadzky.
Simply pass a non-serializable object as a parameter to a method, for instance:

```
public interface OnActionInterface {
    void onPositiveButtonClicked(Activity activity);
    void onNegativeButtonClicked(Activity activity);
}
```

See my full answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37071472/2914140.

Answer (score -1):

Simply *extend* a `Serializable` to the interface like this:

```
public interface PlayerLambda extends Serializable {
    public void updateWatchedProgress(int progress);
}
```