# Parceable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: android, ioexception, parcelable, serializable

I am getting this error :

```
                FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = game.Level)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java)
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java)
        at menu.AreaAdapter$1.onClick(AreaAdapter.java:93)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: menu.AreaActivity
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
```

When running this :

```
holder.butArea.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), game.LevelActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("switchlevel", LevelSwitchCase.getLevel(currentLevel, (pos+1),mContext));
                myIntent.putExtra("level",currentLevel);
                myIntent.putExtra("area", (pos+1));

                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
```

game.level is implementing serializable and getting the error when launching the intent (v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);)

level and area are just integers and switchlevel is a level I am getting (implements Serializable)

Comment: when trying to serialize whatever object is put into the extra "switchlevel", the exception is thrown. Post the code of that class or look carefully at it and see what could be causing an I/O exception when serializing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Context is not Serializable.
To fix this error I declared Context like this(variable doesnt serialize) :

```
  public transient Context mContext;
```

or you can implement Parceable.

Answer (score 4):

If your level class has non primitive members they should also implement serializable.

Comment: Normally every object I use there is implementing Serializable , could it be an other problem?

Answer (score 0):

For those who use context or other non-serializable objects inside an interface. Simply pass it as a parameter to a method, for instance:

```
public interface OnActionInterface {
    void onPositiveButtonClicked(Activity activity);
    void onNegativeButtonClicked(Activity activity);
}
```

Then create a standalone class like:

```
public class SomeClass implements OnActionInterface, Serializable {
    private String action;

    public SomeClass(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClicked(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClicked(Activity activity) {
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

After that you can use objects of this class inside intents.